# Selenium swtiching from nose to pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, nose

I'm thinking about switching from our current testing framework nose w/ nose-testconfig to py.test. Any suggestion how to overwrite the following code specifically setup/teardown below using pytest fixtures

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase, Navigation):
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    browser = Browser.getDriver((config['browser']).lower())

    cls.driver = EventFiringWebDriver(browser, MyListener())
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()

    try:
        cls.driver.get(config['url'])
    except KeyError:
        cls.driver.get(DEV_ENV_URL)

def run(self, result=None):
    super(BaseTestCase, self).run(MyTestResult(result, self))


@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.driver.quit()
```

I'd like to be able to pass command line arguments i.e. url, browser, debug etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check out py.test documentation.

Second, there are few things you have to do assuming you want to use fixtures and not `setUp/tearDown`:
Create a new file `conftest.py` where you test cases are. If you place it somewhere else py.test will not find it.

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", action="store", default="chrome", help="Type in browser type")
    parser.addoption("--url", action="store", default=DEV_ENV_URL, help="url")

@pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
def driver(request):
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("--browser")
    url = request.config.getoption("--url")    
    driver = Browser(browser_name).getDriver() #
    driver.get(url) 
    yield driver  # Write your setUp before 'yield'
    driver.quit() # Write tearDown after 'yield'
```

This will make all your tests use this fixture. But there is another problem I can see that your tests inherit from this `BaseTestCase` so if you didn't follow the naming convention that `py.test` supports it will not find your tests (read the docs on that).

There is a lot more to pytest though. As I've said everything in the docs.